# Line under navbar when hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I searched alot about this and couldn't find , how can I make something similar to the navbar here , when you hover on it a line under it will appear like a loading bar .
- example : http://www.thecrewgaming.com/
is it possible only with css or javascript is needed and how ? 
thanks !

I tried this

```
li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 245, 255, 0.2);
    border-bottom-color: #abcdef;
}
li {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    font-size: 0.8889em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    padding-bottom: 0.125em;``
    transition: border-bottom-color 50ms linear 0s;
}
```

but it appears as a normal line and not like a loading bar in the page linked above .

Comment: Hi Mehdi - have a look at the answers below and either mark an answer as accepted, or provide us some sort of feedback so that we may help you further!

Comment: @Frits Already marked , question solved !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple.

You use a `position:absolute;` property on a `::after` pseudo selector.

See the fiddle and the code below:

https://jsfiddle.net/cuv6bxs5/

```css
li {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  background-color: #404040;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li::after {
  background-color: red;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: width 0.35s ease 0s;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ONE</li>
  <li>TWO</li>
  <li>THREE</li>
  <li>FOUR</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want, I've added the background transition in an updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cuv6bxs5/1/

Comment: thanks , it was more straight forward than i thought , i edited some css and it worked perfectly as i wanted it .

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

They did it using the `:after` pseudo selector with `transition` for the animation.

```css
header .menu_links a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: .25s ease all;
    background: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 45px;
}
header .menu_links a:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -100%;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #dd0034;
    transition: .5s ease all;
}
header .menu_links a:hover:after {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menu_links">
    <a href="#">Link A</a>
    <a href="#">Link B</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Nice answer, I see you went the overflow route, and I went for the width route - although you beat me by about a minute so I think +1 :)

Comment: I think it was even less than a minute :) you got +1 from me as well.